# Mod-tool request: change [npc] to [npcs], [villain] to [villains]

Tags: support, tags

Can we get [npc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/npc) changed to [npcs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/npcs) and and [villain](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/villain) to [villains](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/villains)?

It just struck me that [npc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/npc) and [villain](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/villain) are singular when most every other tag we have of this kind is categorical/plural: [monsters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monsters), [races](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/races), [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells), [weapons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons), [house-rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules), [new-players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-players)...

The [npc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/npc) tag has 55 questions right now, which *although* could maybe be retagged over some days without too much front-page churn, the system now prevents creating new tags that just have a trailing *-s* different.

Comment: Also, I really wish high-rep users could just do these near-similar retags manually. "Are you *sure* you want to create this new tag? Maybe ask on meta?" *Yes* I'm sure you blasted machine, I likely have more edits than your own Community user does...

Comment: Take that desire to meta.SE, maybe? Has it already been asked?

Comment: why can't 100k users just be promoted to moderator automatically

Comment: @xenoterracide there exist users who have 100k and yet are still immature enough they shouldn't be trusted with that power as far as they can spit

Comment: Yeah, don't give me a mod diamond. Ye gods. I'd be terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is necessarily a good idea.

There are dozens of singular tags just like there are dozens of plural tags.  Just going to the front page I see gm-pc, wizard, fighter, npc, and new-gm vs monsters, new-players, skills, and races. We could do a statistical analysis on how many are singular vs plural and then synonymize all of one or the other...

Or we could just get along with our day. The singular or plural made sense to someone and apparently continues to.  It does not interfere with finding/applying the tag, searching using the tag, or SEO one bit and I find it hard to justify spending effort to mess with, except for a kind of OCD "wanting things to all look the same." In an emergent folksonomy like site tagging that kind of parallelism will never, and I would argue should never, happen anyway.

Comment: AFAICT, the singular of [[tag:villain]] made sense to someone who comes from a language that doesn't normally form categoricals like plurals are formed, like English does. NPC was created, as far as I can tell, on a question about a singular NPC, by our dearly-departed anon186. But I take your point: there are lots of these. NPC sticks out like a sore thumb to me somehow, but eh.